# Logic within thread is not executed

Tags: java, android, http

```
public void getDataFromHttp(final String userID, final String userPwd){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                String tempUrl = url;
                tempUrl += "?ID=" + userID+"&PW="+userPwd;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(tempUrl);
                    httpResponse = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpGet);
                if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
                {
                    resultString = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
                    Log.i("wow", "result="+resultString);
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,resultString,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if(resultString.equals("true")){
                        myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                    }else {
                        myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

The logic of the thread above is not executed,I tried putting Toast in different locations to detect and found that run() internal code was not executed.

And Here is where to invoke it

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String userID = inputUsername.getText().toString().trim();
            String userPwd = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            if(userID.equals("")||userPwd.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "please type your username or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                getDataFromHttp(userID, userPwd);
            }
        }
```

I used the Android Studio.

I have been bothering for a long time,please help me，very grateful

Comment: Did you try Log in run() method?

Comment: You cannot execute a Toast in the run of the thread. Your app will crash immediately. You should have told us!

Comment: If there is a catch you should call your handler too. With some message.

Comment: If the statuscode is not 200 you should display a message too for the user.

Comment: Log `getStatusCode` which may help more. Also check that you have added internet permission to application

Comment: oh I'm sorry and you are right @greenapps,My app has been crashing until I deleted Toast.

Comment: Sorry but how to log in run() method?@Krish

Comment: When I run on the phone, click the button without any reaction